# Is there a way to redirect a program's output and still have it go to stdout?

Tags: shell, io-redirection

Okay. If I wanted to redirect the output of a program to a file, I'd do something like this

```
prog > file
```

If I wanted to redirect both stdout and stderr to that file, then I'd do

```
prog > file 2>&1
```

This is all well and good if you want the output to go to the file. But what if you want the output to go to the file and yet still go to stdout/stderr? So, the output is saved in the file, but you can still see it on the console as the program is running. Is there a way to do that? And if so, how?

Comment: Terminology: You mean *and still go to the terminal*.  `stdout` is file-descriptor 1, and `foo > some_file` means that a write-only file descriptor opened on `some_file` is foo's stdout.  stdout always goes to stdout.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[`tee`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)) exists for this purpose; it takes a filename argument and writes the data it reads from stdin to both stdout and the file:

```
$ prog 2>&1 | tee file
```

Comment: And for extra bash 4 cuteness: `prog |& tee file`.

Comment: You can also replace 'file' with a named pipe...

Comment: @KevinCantu: A named pipe is just one type of file; this is Unix where everything is a file.  You can also `prog |& tee /dev/tty > file`, which can be useful in the middle of a pipeline, e.g. `foo |& tee /dev/tty | sed 's/.*\r//' > foo.log` to see status-line progress updates on your terminal, but filter them out of a log file.  Or use it to debug a pipeline you're hacking together by letting you see the data at that point.