# How to redirect stderr and stdout to different files and also display in terminal?

Tags: bash, logs, io-redirection

I want to see the output of a command in the terminal as if there was no redirection. 
Also, stderr needs to be redirected to err.log and stdout needs to be redirected to stdout.log.

It would be nice to also have the exact copy of what is shown in terminal, i.e. errors printed as and when it occurs, in a separate file: stdouterr.log.

Comment: I still find this question very familiar. Let me look up... Here is a very similar one http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/4195/250, and here is a related one http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1416/250

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Use the `tee` command as follows:

```
(cmd | tee stdout.log) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee stderr.log
```

`3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` is how you swap stderr and stdout, because tee can only accept stdout.

Take a look at [Unix tee command](http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/tee.shtml) for more advanced redirections using `tee`.

Comment: nice solution. Is there any way to get cmd exit code?

Comment: @turbanoff Replace `cmd` with `(cmd ; echo >exit_code.txt $?)`.

Comment: I believe this should better-preserve the order of things output to the command line: `((cmd | tee stdout.log) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee stderr.log)`

Comment: This solution fails to address: "I want to see the output of a command in the terminal as if there was no redirection." There is a race condition and thus lines output to terminal will be randomly ordered.

Comment: ___Unix tee command___ link doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't this leave the output swapped?

Comment: May I ask why if the parentheses (subshell) are missing, there is nothing going into the stderr? @TTT Why wrapping in the subshell will preserve the order?

Comment: I see it now! It is because of precedence. Redirection is having a higher precedence than pipes. We may use `{ ... ;}` in-place of `( ... )` which is better not spawning extra sub-shells.

Answer (score 7):

I think logging stdout and stderr to two different files is a splendid idea. Does it not make the logs asynchronous? So I tried out the following:

- stdout to "stdout.log" (as dogbane suggested)
- stderror to "stderr.log" (as dogbane suggested)
- all output to "all.log" and
- still be able to see the output on the display (in a separate terminal though!)

`((cmd | tee stdout.log) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee stderr.log) &> all.log`

in another terminal

```
tail -f --sleep-interval=2 all.log
```

Comment: Is it not possible to direct stderr directly to a second tty? Then no logfile is required.

Comment: @StevenLu yes, if you know the name and have permission to write to the second tty that can be done.

Comment: easier would be `&| tee all.log` on the end of the command instead of `&> all.log`

Comment: @Jasen: 2nd time I see `&|` . I understand `&>`, `|&` too, but what does `&|` mean in this context ? I could not find a suitable syntax reference, not on the net, not even consulting the bash manual page "bash(1)"... Tx

Comment: @Cbhihe as far as I can tell it does nothing,  I  meant to say `|&`

Comment: ` >& ` redirects STDOUT and STDERR simultaneously. ` | ` pipes STDOUT only, STDERR still goes to the "screen." ' |& ` pipes STDOUT _and_ STDERR. Thus `cmd |& tee file` is shorthand for `cmd 2>&1 | tee file`

Comment: This solution fails to address: "I want to see the output of a command in the terminal as if there was no redirection." There is a race condition and thus lines output to terminal will be randomly ordered.

Answer (score 3):

@dogbane, Thanks. 
I found another way too which saves both the streams approximately in the order as they would get printed without redirection.

`command 2> >(tee errlog | tee -a bothLog > /dev/tty ) | tee outlog | tee -a bothLog`

But this works only with the shells which supports process substitution.

Comment: This solution fails to address: "I want to see the output of a command in the terminal as if there was no redirection." There is a race condition and thus lines output to terminal will be randomly ordered.