# Redirect output to stdall.log, stderr.log and stdoutput.log + return status code

Tags: bash, io-redirection, tee

I'm already searched for it and found a solution for it [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/54974/213500), but without **return status code** part.

As you can see it uses a sub-shells and I can't get a status code from there, so basing on this answer I want to write something like this:

```
(((cmd; status=$?) | tee stdout.log) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee stderr.log) &> all.log
if [ $status -ne 0 ]
then
  # do something with stderr.log and stdall.log
fi
```

Of course in my example `$status` is not visible in parent shell. How I can modify it to much my needs?

Comment: You could write your exit codes within the subshells to files (`retcode=$(mktemp); [...] ( subshellcommand; echo $? > $retcode )`) perhaps.

Comment: @DopeGhoti: Operation on files could be a performance issue (in lots of that calls), but in my case it's not a problem, thanks!