# Is it possible to "fork" STDOUT to two different locations?

Tags: streaming, tee, stdout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way in bash to redirect output and still have it go to stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/is-there-a-way-in-bash-to-redirect-output-and-still-have-it-go-to-stdout)

Let's say I do:

```
ps -ef | grep httpd
```

to see if apache is running or not, but I also want to "dump" the output of `ps -ef` into a file at the same time. Like this:

```
ps -ef  --- grep http
       |
        --- > file
```

Is it possible to fork STDOUT in parallel like this? The above is only an example so little hacks like dumping to the file and then grepping the file isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. You are looking for `tee` not `fork()`:

```
ps -ef | tee file | grep http
```

Comment: Oh that's what `tee` does! I've only come in contact with it a couple times but thanks for clearing that up. Does it work for the other standard streams?

Comment: @MaxMackie: It works on whatever it is given. Unless you specifically tell the shell otherwise it will only receive the STDOUT of the proper being piped to it.