# How do I prevent less from clearing the screen on exit?

Tags: bash, less

I often pipe commands to `less` in order to read through the output (e.g. compiler errors).

```
MyCommand | less
```

This is great because it makes trawling through large amounts of output easy, but when I exit `less` the output is gone. How can I make the output still visible after quitting less?

This question differs from [Is there a way to redirect a program's output and still have it go to stdout?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4195/is-there-a-way-in-bash-to-redirect-output-and-still-have-it-go-to-stdout) because that question relates to output to a text file via `tee`, which, as far as I know, doesn't provide a facility to split output between `less` and `stdout`.

Comment: @jasonwryan the question is similar but the accepted answer appears limited to redirecting output to files, at least that's my understanding of the `tee` command. I am not sure what the rules are regarding this situation but I don't think marking this as a duplicate would benefit the community unless the answer to that question is reviewed.

Comment: @jasonwryan: I agree; they're not the same question. The other one is a shell question; Arman's question is really about `less`; namely, how to get it to leave the displayed text in the console's scrollable display history buffer. ... P.S. Arman: You might want to [edit] your question and retag is as a `/less` question.

Comment: @Arman I edited your title & question some more, please feel free to revert my edit if I've misunderstood what you're asking.

Comment: @derobert that seems fine.

Comment: They aren't duplicates, they are about totally different things: he wants info about the problematic ncurses behavior of the less command, and this hasn't anything to do with the fd redirections! Shame to you!

Comment: As a protest against the unfair robo-closing policy here you get an upvote from me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using [`less -X`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/less):

> Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization strings to the terminal.

That will leave any text on-screen behind before and after paging. So:

```
command | less -X
```

will have the effect you want. Note that this output will still be wrong (duplicated lines) if you ever scrolled up - that's unavoidable without without writing to a file.

You can also set the environment variable `LESS` to a value that contains `X` to do this by default for every invocation of `less`.

If you want to write to a file without resorting to `tee`, you can use the `less -o filename` or `--log-file=filename` options.

Comment: Or if you only realize after starting `less` that you want to save the output, you can use `-o filename` interactively (just like most `less` options).  You can't change `-X` from inside `less`, though, and it wouldn't be useful because that would leave you in the "alternate" mode of your VT100-style terminal; switching back from that to the normal mode where the scrollback goes is the real reason the screen clears when you exit.

Answer (score 6):

You can use:

```
 command | tee filename.out | less
```

and then examine filename.out via an editor if you still need to see the output after running the less command.

Another idea is to change your term setting to use a dumb terminal type.  You'd have to experiment with this one.

Answer (score 3):

If the issue is just that less is "clearing the screen" when you quit it you can avoid that behavior specifically by telling less not to send the terminal/termcap init/de-init strings when it starts and stops. You do this by using `-X`. So try `command | less -X`.

That may have other side-effects if those strings do things that are actually necessary but I don't expect that to be the case for you here.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try the command `more` in place of `less`. It will still paginate the output and allow you to scroll through it nicely, but in the end your terminal will retain the output as if it were not piped through anything.

Comment: Since `less` is more powerful than `more`, suggesting `more` is only moderately useful. For instance, with `less` you can scroll forth and back through the text even it is the output from a pipe - `more` is not capable of doing that that.

Comment: I suppose. I suggested it because it fills what the question desired, and no other functionality was mentioned.