# How to make “less” exit with clearing the screen?

Tags: terminal, less, macos

I have a question just opposite to [Is there any way to exit "less" without clearing the screen?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38634/is-there-any-way-to-exit-less-without-clearing-the-screen): my `less` exits without clearing the screen, but I have never used `-X`.

The options I use is as follows:

```
$ echo $LESS 
-N -g -i -M -R -w -z-4
$ echo $LESSOPEN
$
$ echo $TERM
ansi
```

I remember when my `less` started to change its behavior: when I was trying to type something to another application but my cursor was in the terminal with `less` opening. When I realized I'm typing into a wrong place and tried to quit `less`, the file contents start to remaining to my terminal. I'm using MacOS terminal (not `iTerm2`).

As @roaima suggested, my issue is to get the `less`'s standard behavior without `-X`. However, `-+X` does not work; and `-X` is not in `LESS`.

I'm using `OSX` Terminal.app, not `iTerm2`.

Comment: I am fairly sure that we have both forms of this question already.  We definitely have https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/336609/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149970/ ,  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224213/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38634/ .  We also have https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/427274/ .

Answer (score 1):

If you really want `less` to clear the screen when it exits you can redefine the command like this

```
less() { command less "$@"; clear; }
```

On the other hand, if you want `less` to save the original content of the screen and restore that when it exits, this should be standard behaviour. (It's managed through the `ti` and `te` entries of `TERMINFO` and/or `TERMCAP`. These are set according to the terminal type as evidenced with `echo $TERM`.)

You can try forcing off the `-X` option with

```
less -+X
```

But if that doesn't work either, provide the result of running an `echo $TERM` command, and it should be possible to determine what the `ti` and `te` values are, and therefore why they're not saving and restoring the screen.

Comment: Thank you @roaima, My issue is to get standard behavior, but `less -+X` does not work. `$ echo $TERM` returns `ansi`

Comment: Have you read the [answer I've highlighted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/389126/100397) in the duplicate?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not using iTerm2. I'm having this issue in the OSX Terminal.app and I can't find anything similar to "Save lines to scrollback in alternate screen mode" in its preference... Or did I missed something?

Comment: Yes! You're not updating your question with this information you gradually disclose. People can't know what you don't tell them.